# Xcode delete pod files folder and schema after discard all changes

Tags: ios, xcode

when I use Xcode 9 source control everything was good.

When I updated Xcode up to 10 and when I press discard all changes - Xcode has deleted pod files, run schemas, and one folder where I store .xliff files.

When I pressed to 'Discard all changes' I see this alert

[image: Xcode alert]

I know that I can reinstall Pods and made new schema, but I don't won't do it every time.

Please give me advise to fix this problem.
Please give me my source control back)))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I solve it with this way. 
In Terminal

cd "your project dir"

git add

Comment: Not works for me. xliff file and Pods are missed, only schemas not deleted.